# Is there physical significance to the Gateaux derivative of entropy?

Tags: entropy, information, functional-derivatives, thermal-conduction

Is there any physical "force" generated by a difference in entropy or information between two regions? There is some confusion between thermodynamic entropy and information entropy, but one could imagine a region of low entropy and region of high entropy, a "flow" from the high entropy region to the low one.

Consider the entropy functional $S(D)=-k\int_X D\log(D)$, where $D$ is a probability distribution on phase space $X$. Classically, the measure on $X$ is $dxdp/h$. The maximum entropy distribution is the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution, $D^*=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta u}$, where $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$ and $u(x,p)=p^2/2m$. It is a Gaussian which doesn't depend on position.

One can take a [functional derivative of $S$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368563/functional-derivative-of-differential-entropy) in some direction $h \in L^1(X)$, obtaining

$$-k\int_X (1+\log(D))h$$

At the maximum $D^*$, the "directional derivative" is $-k\int_x (1-\beta u - \log(Z))h$.

Comment: There would have to be some means of information transport.  A hard drive sitting on a table will not begin to leak its information to nearby objects, although it will lose that information to random processes over time."

Comment: Right. If I heat the plate yo to 1000K, then it’ll radiate in IR, etc. Our hard drives are relatively small, perhaps not the right order of magnitude to notice. Isn’t “losing that information to random processes over time” the definition of information leak? I think the question here is how “random” are those processes.

Comment: I was thinking mainly of bit flips due to cosmic rays and quantum tunneling.

Comment: Two sources certainly. Quantum tunneling is closer, a sort of unavoidable outward “pressure” that prevents one from simply having a (huge) static hard drive. I don’t know how such an effect scales with the density of qubits.

Comment: I think (at least in principle) you should be able to solve the condition that the functional derivative (or "Gateaux derivative") of the entropy wrt the distribution over microstates is zero, to derive the Boltzmann distribution. In non-equilibrium fluid mechanics, you can have flows from high entropy to low entropy regions (sometimes a gradient of entropy appears), but this would be a gradient with respect to space, not a functional derivative, and is not an equilibrium situation so it doesn't make sense to maximize the entropy for the whole system.

Comment: I still think (as in a comment on another answer) that you should be careful about using the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) since the argument of the log should be dimensionless but $D$ is not dimensionless since it is a distribution for a continuous variable.